# Show block for pages of every content type but one; including the front page

Tags: blocks, nodes

I've created a custom block, and I want to show it on every page including the front page, *except* for pages of one specific content type.

In block settings, under "Visibility Settings", there is a list of checkboxes for each content type.  If none are checked, the block shows on every page; but if any are checked, the block only appears on pages with the checked content type.  So I tried checking everything except the one content type I want to exclude.

Except that this *also* excludes the block from the front page.  It appears as though the front page doesn't have a content type you can choose to make the block show up.

Is there a way to get my block on the front page as well, while still excluding some content types from showing it?

Comment: Did you see the "Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only) " option. Why not use that?

Answer (score 2):

The [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) module is perfect for this task.

1. Download and enable the Context module and add a new context under Structure -> Context
2. Add a 'Path' condition and set it to `<front>` http://d.pr/i/x4R5
3. Add a 'Node type' condition and check every node type, except the one where you don't want your block to show http://d.pr/i/PSO4
4. Add a reaction called 'Blocks', on the right check the block you want to show when the first to conditions are met, and click 'Add+' next to the region where you want your block to show. http://d.pr/i/a3RG
5. Save the context and that's it

Also make sure to leave 'Require all conditions' unchecked so the context will activate if the first or second condition is met.